# Email profile from local PC with powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I have desktop PC working with **Windows 10** and different **Outlook 2007**

I want get their email/username  from their local profile what I mean is this

[image]

All I want is the `username` and `email` from the profile with PowerShell, what it the code can do that?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: `New-Object -ComObject 'Outlook.Application'` but it gives me information about the profile

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87573e22-eac4-4a0c-8f41-1143ff5ec979/powershell-script-to-fetch-info-of-all-outlook-accounts-in-users-machine?forum=ITCG

Comment: also not work it show only the Registry files details

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to get the right solution :
 `Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"`
`$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application`
`$namespace =$Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")`
`$namespace.Accounts| select -Property SmtpAddress`

`SmtpAddress`

`-----------`
`somone@email.com`

also you can get the data files and information about emails using `$namespace` property.